# How to use Cacheable using the result Object's id?

Tags: java, ehcache, spring-cache

```
public class MyClass{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    Long id;

    private AnotherClass anotherClass;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "another_id")
    @Cacheable(value = "getAnotherClass", unless = "#result == null", key = "#id")
    public AnotherClass getAnotherClass(){
        return anotherClass;
    }
}

public class AnotherClass{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    Long id;
}
```

There are 2 classes. `MyClass` contains a foreign key to `AnotherClass`.

I need to cache the `getAnotherClass` in such a way that it caches using the `id` of `AnotherClass`.

How to do it?

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/ 
have you tried this way?

Comment: Using `@Cacheable(value = "getAnotherClass")` still causes a lot of actual DB calls.

Answer (score 1):

1. Spring **@Cacheable cannot be used without method parameter**. 
   First time a method annotated with @Cacheable gets called, it gets executed and it’s return value is stored in Cache using a key[pamater of the instance passed as method parameter]. 
   Next time, if the method gets called using same key[same parameter for instance], the result is returned directly from Cache, without executing the method.
2. You are trying to mix the ORM(hibernate) with spring cache which seems to be a bad idea, instead you can utilize the **second level cache provided by hibernate** refer https://www.journaldev.com/2980/hibernate-ehcache-hibernate-second-level-cache
3. If you still want to use spring cacheable, write a service to implement spring caching. Have a condition to check if object available in cache repository else fetch using ORM refer ("Combine @CachePut and @Cacheable to optimize cache use" section in https://www.foreach.be/blog/spring-cache-annotations-some-tips-tricks)